# clarify basic probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

You have a loaded die.

$A =$ even numbers

$B =$ odd numbers

$P(A)=3/4$

$P(B)=1/4$

$P(\{1\})=1/12$

$P(\{2\})=1/4$

How was $P(\{1\})$ and $P(\{2\})$ calculated?
Is it beacuse there are 3 odds and 3 evens so the chance of 1 odd (1) is 1/3(1/4)=1/12 and likewise, the chance of an even (2) is 1/3(3/4)=1/4?

Comment: $P({1})$ and $P\{2\})$ are not _calculated_; they are apparently part of the information _given_ to you. The real question is _What is the_ **question** that you are asking? What probabilities are you asked to find?

Comment: Are the values $P(\{1\})$ and $P(\{2\})$ given to you? Or were they what you supposed to calculate? If they were what you're supposed to calculate, there's not enough information from what you wrote beforehand to calculate the values.

Answer (score 0):

$P(\{1\}) = P(B\cap \{1\}) = P(B)\cdot P(\{1\}|B) = \dfrac{1}{4}\cdot \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{12}$, and similarly the other one is: $\dfrac{3}{4}\cdot \dfrac{1}{3} = \dfrac{1}{4}$

Comment: I think the question is *why* $P(\{1\} \mid B) = \frac{1}{3}$ when you don't know how the die is weighted. In other words, why should $P(\cdot\mid B)$ and $P( \cdot  \mid A)$ be considered uniform?

Comment: I think the question is not clear. I agree with professor Dilip's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

If you roll the dice 12 times, you'll get 9 times 2, 4 or 6, and 3 times 1, 3 or 5. Said differently, three 2, three 4, three 6, one 1, one 3 and one 5.

On average, of course, and assuming that the even and odd numbers are equiprobable inside their category.

Comment: I think the question is *why* is selecting an even (resp. odd) equally probable knowing that you have a loaded die?

Comment: The problem statement being mute about imbalance among the even or among the odd numbers, you have to hypothesize this.